# Python HMAC: TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode

Tags: python

I am having a slight problem with HMAC. When running this piece of code:

```
signature = hmac.new(
    key=secret_key,
    msg=string_to_sign,
    digestmod=sha1,
)
```

I get a strange error:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 133, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

When I print string_to_sign, it is a proper string like this:

```
GET
\n
\n
application/json
\n
\n
\n
```

What does the error mean? Is it because of new lines?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue5285).

Comment: @Faust Thanks. Could you post it as answer? I used django.utils.encoding.smart_bytes to convert from unicode to byte string and then it works.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As asked I'll post this as an answer.
The error that you faced is a *feature* of Python's HMAC. It does not accept unicode.
This *feature* is described [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue5285).

HMAC is a function which works at byte level. For this reason in Python 3 it accepts only `bytes`. In Python 2 we don't have `bytes` so it accepts only `str`.

Answer (score 16):

Ensure that "key" and "msg" is a string.such as:

> s = hmac.new(str(secretkey), str(message), digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't want to write in our API docs that you should convert the payload to ASCII or drop Unicode characters before comparing digests, I've used the following solution:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

def sign_request(self, secret, data):
    return hmac.new(
        key=bytearray(secret, 'utf-8'),
        msg=bytearray(data, 'utf-8'),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()
```

- `bytearray` turns my unicode string into bytes using the `utf-8` encoding.
- `key` and `msg` are bytes parameters (like `hmac` library is expecting).

Answer (score 1):

*In python 2*

If you code it as:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import time

def gen_signature(key, strsome, expires=0):
    expires = int(time.time()) + 600 if expires == 0 else expires
    _2_signature = '%s\n%s\n' % (expires, strsome)
    # hmac.new(key, msg, digestmod) bytearray(secret, 'utf-8')
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key, _2_signature, hashlib.sha1).digest())
    return signature


gen_signature('xxxxxxx', 'strsome')
```

you get an error like the one you provided.
However, if you use `bytearray(key, 'utf-8')` in place of the raw key variable and `bytearray(_2_signature, 'utf-8')` in place place of the _2_signature variable, it should work properly.

For example:

```
def gen_signature(key, strsome, expires=0):
    expires = int(time.time()) + 600 if expires == 0 else expires
    _2_signature = '%s\n%s\n' % (expires, strsome)
    # hmac.new(key, msg, digestmod) bytearray(secret, 'utf-8')
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytearray(key, 'utf-8'), bytearray(_2_signature, 'utf-8'), hashlib.sha1).digest())
    return signature


gen_signature('xxxxxxx', 'strsome')
```